# What are folders for?

Tags: fallout-4

I keep finding them around the Wasteland, but have yet to find a purpose for them. Are they a red herring item, or do they have some use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Folders actually do have one function - they have a weight of 0 but can be sold for 1 cap each, so there's no drawback to picking them up other than the time spent doing so.

Answer (score 8):

They have no known use.  They can't even be scrapped for materials.

[image]

Arguably they could be used for "decorating," or collected to see how many you find (and so on), but serve no in-game function - the same as burnt magazines, burnt books and some other miscellaneous items I can't think of off the top of my head.

Comment: @DangerZone I believe these are the items that have no scrap value.. I know for sure the burnt items are in that group. You can sell them for 0 caps, hehe.

Comment: @DCShannon Can you show me a screen shot of this? I have not found any way of getting rid of those objects except selling them for nothing.. I can only pick them up and move them or store them (Maybe not the folder? I was focusing more on the burnt objects)

Comment: @HopelessN00b That'll do it. +1 for research

Comment: Burnt magazines sell for 1 cap each, burnt books are the ones with no value.  Hubris comics has enough burnt comics to walk away with almost 200 caps just from them

Comment: Figured out where I was getting the idea you can break them down into plastic. You can break down *Files* into plastic and wood, which looks like a cardboard box full of folders.

Answer (score 3):

Because of their lack of use anywhere else, and their lack of weight as well, they are the perfect ammunition for the Junk Jet, alongside the Pre-war cash stacks

Comment: Isn't the Junk Jet limited to only shooting Junk? Folders are categorized as Misc.

Comment: I'll confirm when I get home and update my answer accordingly :)

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the fallout wiki:

"A plain, empty manila folder used for organizing papers. They weigh nothing and can be sold for a single cap, but otherwise have no practical purpose in-game.

There is no reason not to pick up Folders, they are equally as valuable as caps."

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to belief of folders being useless, they can sell for 1 cap each which in my personal case has helped me a lot in collecting the caps needed for some items or even to build shops in settlements since these need caps to buid them

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this simply restates the information contained in a previous answer. You might want to consider adding some more information to differentiate your answer.