# What items look like scrappable junk, but can't be scrapped?

Tags: fallout-4

Almost everything you can pickup in Fallout 4 can be scrapped for components, but not *quite* everything.

Some things clearly are not junk, even though they can be scrapped. As far as I'm aware, this includes all non-legendary weapons and armor and mods when attached, so ignore those. Some things are pretty clearly not junk, and cannot be scrapped. As far as I'm aware, this includes aid items, so ignore those. If you know an exception to these broad strokes, please mention it.

This leaves Misc items. I think some of these can be broken down (in workshop mode), but many cannot. Folders, for instance, [cannot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/246364/108003).

**What items are in this category?**

An exhaustive list would be nice if it's short enough, but the point is to avoid picking up things I can't scrap, so focus on ones one is likely to see, and on describing them in a way that can be remembered.

Comment: I have to assume those downvotes are because this looks like a "list question", but it's a finite list that will not need to be updated over time or added to. If there's another reason, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Not a downvoter, but I'd assume people probably just don't like the "Give me a list of..." questions. I wouldn't expect this list to be very large at all... But many lists are finite, given enough time ;)

Comment: I don't know why you expect the list to be short enough to fit the SE format. Fallout 4 has *hundereds*, if not *thousands*, of items. Of the seven categories in the player inventory (which in fact do not encompass all items in the game, nor all that can be scrapped), only three hold items which are commonly expected to be scrapped. Performing exhaustive testing or code analysis of all items in Fallout 4, and providing a list of what can or cannot be scrapped would be *far* beyond the appropriate scope for a single SE answer.

Comment: @Iszi Hmm... In my answer, I focused mainly on the items that appear to be random junk, but weren't scrappable, since they show up in the 'Misc' tab (such as his example, folders). I can see that the way the question is currently worded... that it could be interpreted as a question for a full list of non-scrappable items, which would include ammo, mods, and aid (as you pointed out in your answer). Maybe adding a bit of focus to the question would help clarify.

Comment: The biggest problem with this question, I think, is the specific listing of Folders. That blows the scope wide beyond what's normally expected to be scrap-able in the first place, by including an item in the Misc category. (All of which, to my knowledge, cannot be scrapped - albeit, as @king14nyr has noted, there are some which can be used as ingredients.) Perhaps narrow it down to something like "What weapons/armor/junk, if any, cannot be scrapped?" and you'll find a list of a more SE-appropriate size.

Comment: @king14nyr Alright, that makes sense. Let me add some details.

Comment: @Iszi Does that seem better?

Comment: @DCShannon At this point, I think you could just simplify the whole thing to one of: "What items in the Misc category can be scrapped?" or "What items in the Misc category cannot be scrapped?". (Whichever you expect might be shorter.)

Comment: @Iszi That might be what the question effectively works out to, but that's not the question. If there's an exception to those rules, it would be good to know.

Comment: I'm still not sure we won't end up with a rather overly-large list here. I haven't found anything that exhaustively sorts items by inventory category or scrap-ability yet. But [one list of item IDs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J9quAMtGK70aptz0t5teqWHGZJ9T9uvJmzNEBJEB36Q/htmlview?sle=true) on Google Docs has over 1800 unique entries. Many of these are non-inventory items, of course, but I think that does say a bit about the scale of this question.

Comment: @Iszi I think king14nyr has a link to the answer in his answer, and it has less than 30 items on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge, all the items that seem like junk, but are not scrappable, appear in the 'Misc' section of your inventory instead of the 'Junk' tab. You might have noticed that when collecting folders, for example, they sit in the 'Misc' tab of your Pip-Boy inventory until you remove them yourself, and do not move when performing the "store all junk" action at a workshop.

That being said, the most complete list I've been able to find is at the [Fallout 4 Wiki article on Miscellaneous Items](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_miscellaneous_items), more specifically the "Other Items" section. This section contains all of the items I've run across that seem like junk, but was unable to scrap:

- Bobby Pin
- Book Return Token/Overdue book
- Burnt Book/Textbook
- Burnt Fashion/Lifestyle/Trade Magazines
- Burnt Grognak/Manta-Man/Unstoppables Comics
- Cybernetic Limb Actuator
- Cybernetic Pain Inhibitor
- Delivered Boston Bugle
- Eyebot/Mr. Handy/Mr. Gutsy/Protectron/Robot Parts/Sentry Bot Models
- Folder
- Lab Scale
- Napkin
- Stingwing Barb
- Subway Token
- Vault-Tec Lunchbox

Some items in this list, while not scrappable, still serve some purpose for crafting or gameplay. Stingwing barbs and Vault-Tec lunchboxes are used in crafting. Bobby pins are, of course, for lockpicking. Overdue books/book return tokens are used at [Book Return terminals](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/244832/where-should-i-return-all-of-my-overdue-library-books), and Subway Tokens are for [paying Subway Stewards](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/244401/how-can-i-avoid-being-killed-by-subway-stewards-ticket-inspectors#244545).

Furthermore, not all of these items are weightless. Whereas collecting all folders might add some clutter to your inventory, collecting burnt books/textbooks also has the negative effect of adding 1 weight each (with a value of 0), so should be avoided to prevent being over-encumbered.

Needless to say, other items that appear in the 'Misc' inventory tab, such as holotapes, notes, quest items, etc., cannot be scrapped. The one exception to this seems to be the [RFID Device](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/RFID_device), given to you during the quest "[Jackpot](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Jackpot_(quest))". It is not marked as a quest item, which would prevent it from being scrapped.

Comment: Wait... what's a Vault-Tec Lunchbox used for?

Comment: @Iszi [Bottlecap Mine](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Bottlecap_mine_(Fallout_4)).

Comment: I think that list on the Fallout Wiki pretty much answers it. I was looking for that and couldn't find it before posting the question.

Comment: If you copy over the contents of that list, so that it's not just in a link, I might just accept this.

Comment: @DCShannon I've added it. I typically try to avoid putting lists from the Wiki in answers, since that can change so often and make our answers out of date. This list shouldn't change often, though... We can edit in any changes, if need be.

Comment: Are there any items in Misc that *can* be scrapped?

Comment: I rewrote the question a bit to refocus on the issue as encountered while actually playing the game. I think your answer is still fine as it is, but just a heads-up.

Comment: @Iszi I noticed yesterday that the RFID you get for DIA quests is in the Misc tab, but can be scrapped for a couple things, including fiberglass.

Comment: @DCShannon Hmm... what an interesting case. Looking into it, the RFID Device isn't marked as a quest item, although it seems like it should be. I assume you couldn't finish the 'Jackpot' quest without it, although I've never attempted it. **And** it is in the Misc. tab, which typically doesn't allow items to be broken down. I'll edit my answer for correctness, but now I'm on the hunt to see if this is a one-off, or if there were any other items like this.

Answer (score 2):

Your inventory is broken into several categories:

- **Weapons**
- **Apparel**
- Aid
- Misc
- **Junk**
- Mods
- Ammo

Categories in bold are the ones which contain items which are generally easy to break down into scrap. All non-legendary Weapons can be broken down manually at a workbench. Most non-legendary armor in the Apparel category can be broken down manually at a workbench as well, but not all Apparel is armor and there's even some exceptions which are armor. All Junk will be automatically be broken down as needed during crafting.

Workstations also have a somewhat-hidden inventory of items that can be used in settlement construction, which the player has either built or collected and chosen to put into storage there. When not labeled as critical for a mission, these items can be scrapped in construction mode after you place them in the environment.

It's conceivable that some Aid/Misc/Mods/Ammo items (and non-armor Apparel) could be scrapped if they were dropped in the environment and then viewed in construction mode. However, I have not thoroughly tested this myself and I personally consider it to be generally unlikely. (Maybe the non-armor Apparel will go, but probably not the rest.)

At the very least, I do know that most - if not all - food items (which would be collected under Aid) cannot be scrapped. I find it generally annoying since it just adds a bit more hassle to cleanup of things like Blamco Mac & Cheese whenever I'm taking over a new settlement.

Comment: Weapons/Apparel can also be 'scrapped' by dropping them in a settlement, entering workshop mode, hovering over them and selecting 'Scrap'. This technique is especially useful as it works for items that cannot normally be modded and thus do not show in the Weapon/Apparel workbench screens